# Using Windows Visual Themes with Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks, dwm

this is my first post on this website,

Anyway, I recently started trying to make a win32 app, and its been going well so far. Then I wanted to add aero to my app (as in not just the borders). So I looked it up online and one tutorial said I have to include dwmapi.h. This is in the Windows SDK. I don't know how to add this to Code::Blocks. By the way, I am using MinGW as my compiler. Also I tried using the MSVC 10 (VS2010) compiler in Code::Blocks, but I got a bunch of errors when I tried to use it, relating to the compilers/linkers not being found.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind, I figured it out. I updated to the nightly build of Code::Blocks and it had an easy preset to help me set up the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to do custom drawing of controls and theme interfaces, all you need to do to support the visual themes is to add the [appropriate manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you want to extend Aero Glass into your client area, look at [`DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea ()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and family.
There are various [articles and tutorials online about how to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx). I don't know specifics of using it with Code::Blocks though.

Comment: well I want to make the whole window be able to have aero, not just the border, so I'm not sure what that requires?

Comment: kinda like this image: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/VGGlassIntro/dlgclocklogo.png)

Comment: I also figured out how to do the aero glass in the whole window, see my other question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022391/how-do-i-set-the-windowclassx-hbrbackground-alpha-channel-c)

Comment: In this question I was just asking how to add the SDK so I could use DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea() which is in dwmapi.h, which I was having trouble setting up. But the SVN of Code::Blocks had a preset for me to set up the SDK which worked.